# How to find min and max values for each key in hash

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to get the min and max values for each key:

```
DATA:
$VAR1 = { '0.0' => {  
                    '0.0',
                    '1.2',
                    '2.0',
                    '0.4',
                   },
          '0.2' => {
                    '2.3',
                    '0.1',
                    '0.0',
                   }
        };
```

my code snippet:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

for my $key (sort {$a <=> $b} keys (%seedhash))
{
    my ($min, $max) = minmax values %{$seedhash{$key}};
    print "$key {";
    for my $values (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %{$seedhash{$key}})
    {
        print "$values, ";
    }
    print "} $min : $max \n";
}
```

My desired output would be

```
0.0 {0.0, 1.2, 2,0, 0.4, } 0.0 : 2.0
0.2 {0.0, 0.1, 2.3, } 0.0 : 2.3
```

However my output is this:

```
0.0 {0.0, 1.2, 2,0, 0.4, }  HASH(0x13d13ec0) : HASH(0x142dad70)
0.2 {0.0, 0.1, 2.3, } HASH(0x137e7810) : HASH(0x142fef10)
```

I'm not sure if my syntax is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your DATA makes no sense. Is it really the dump of `%seedhash`? If not, please provide it.

Comment: @M42, the DATA is revised

Comment: Your DATA still makes no sense. Are you sure this the result of a dump  ?

Comment: No, it is not a dump. A hashref *cannot* contain an odd number of elements. (If you put an odd number in, the final key will implicitly receive a value of `undef`.) Data::Dumper also doesn't format hashrefs that way. Please show the actual data structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
my %seedhash = ( '0.0' => [
                    '0.0',
                    '1.2',
                    '2.0',
                    '0.4',
                   ],
          '0.2' => [
                    '2.3',
                    '0.1',
                    '0.0',
                   ]
);

use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

for my $key (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %seedhash)
{
    my ($min, $max) = minmax @{$seedhash{$key}};
    print "$key {";
    for my $values (sort {$a <=> $b} @{$seedhash{$key}})
    {
        print "$values, ";
    }
    print "} $min : $max \n";
}
```

output

```
0.0 {0.0, 0.4, 1.2, 2.0, } 0.0 : 2.0
0.2 {0.0, 0.1, 2.3, } 0.0 : 2.3
```